# page reload and image caching

Tags: javascript, image, http, caching, reload

I find out that whenever I do window.location.reload(), the requests for the images on my web page is sent to the server. The images are cached with an expiry date, thus I think they should be loaded from cache instead. Because all I get from the server is 304 unmodified, I have a lot of images on the page so I don't want a request for each image when the page refreshes.

My question is why is the browser try to contact the server instead of loading them from cache?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say the images are cached with an expiry date, do you mean you are manually setting the HTTP Expires header? Most servers send a Last-Modified header by default, which is used in determining if an image need to be updated (which results in a 304 Not Modified result, as discussed below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`304 Not Modified` indicates to the browser that it should reload from cache. If you look at the bytes sent it should be less than 1kb when reloading from cache.

Comment: I understand 304 Not Modified reads from cache if it's not modified, but I just want it to load from cache without checking with the server..

Comment: That's not how the web works. If it's a matter of changing content then you'll need to use ajax to fetch specific areas of the page and change them but doing a `window.location.reload()` is for all intents and purposes indistinguishable from the user clicking the reload button in the browser.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to manually set the HTTP Expires header to not send the additional requests to the server, as explained in the Caching Method 3 section [here](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/).

Comment: Hi netfire, the Expires Header works except when you call window.location.reload(), it will actually go to the server to verify if anything has changed.. I want the expire header to work when window.location.reload() is called..

Comment: Hi JaredMcAteer, I know the html on the page is changing, but none of the images are changing. My goal is when I refresh the page, I don't have to send out unnecessary image requests. window.location.reload() tries to verify everything.. I guess that how it's implemented..

Comment: You could refresh the page by calling window.location.href="/page/url", instead of calling the reload function, but it sounds like ajax would be a much better solution here. That way additional requests aren't made for js files and css stylesheets and the browser doesn't have to re-render the whole page again.